# How to insert pictures in the application from the network

Tags: ios, image-scaling, image-size

My question is how to insert pictures to the application from the network. I have news application. I want to insert a picture in the news feed. How to crop an image - if I crop the picture to fit the screen, it turns out beaten, visible square pixels, which is not nice. I have a server stored the image size of 700 by 410 pixels. At the iPhone 5 screen width of 320 pixels from the iPhone 6 is different. I'll crop the picture on the device. I guess in advance on the server to store the image at different resolutions, is that correct?

Comment: which network you use...

Comment: @Maulik 3G or WiFi, if you about library networking this is restkit

Comment: @Maulik not that I do not need